# C++ string error with "find_first_of" function

Tags: c++, string

I want to get the word which is between two quotes so im using std::string::find_first_of
but pos2 and pos1 are same values , it causes error.

```
  std::string ss="<tag2 name = \"Name1\">";
  std::size_t pos1=ss.find_first_of("\"");
  std::size_t pos2=ss.find_first_of("\"",pos1);//i'am using pos1 as a base position to get pos2.
  std::cout<<pos1<<std::endl<<pos2;
```

Comment: "[I]t causes error" is unfortunately a pretty bad problem description. *What* error? *How*? What did you expect, and what did you get? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry about that , i am newbie . Im trying to get the word between two quote for example "Name1" . I got position of first quote-which is pos1- without any problem but I couldn't get position of second quote -which is pos2- . pos2 and pos1 always come up with same value.I'm using pos1 as a base position to get pos2 but like i said pos1 and pos2 always come up with same value.

Comment: @EkremKöse OK well see the answers below.

Comment: If `pos1` is the position of the first `"` character and you start looking for quotes at  that position, you're obviously going to find the one at that position again. You need to start looking _after_ that position, not at that position. Also, if you're trying to find a single character just use `find('"')` not `find_first_of("\"")`, because `find_first_of` is for finding the first one of a set of multiple characters. It's pointless (and slower) to use it for a single character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the **next occurence** of " after position pos1, you can use `ss.find_first_of('\"',pos1+1);`

`ss.find_last_of('\"',pos1);` will look for a quote starting at the first quote you found but looking backwards/towards the beginning of the string. You can use `ss.find_last_of('\"');` to find the last occurence of a quote in the whole string.

In your example, `ss.find_first_of('\"',pos1+1);` and `ss.find_last_of('\"');` will yield the same result because the string contains two quotes and therefore, the second quote is also the last quote.

Comment: He doesn't want to find the next occurance, he wants the **last** occurance

Comment: By my interpretation of "the word which is between two quotes" cannot contain a quote.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the second parameter to `find_last_of`. It is the **last** character to be searched. So you just end up finding the same character again. Remove the second parameter and your code will work

```
std::string ss="<tag2 name = \"Name1\">";
std::size_t pos1=ss.find_first_of("\"");
std::size_t pos2=ss.find_last_of("\"");
std::cout<<pos1<<std::endl<<pos2<<std::endl;
```

Comment: actually i dont want to use find_last_of , because when there is a string like that <b value = "BadVal" size = "10">  i couldn't get value of size , if i use find_last of to get size , it will be like BadVal" size="10;

Answer (score 1):

According to [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/)
, second parameter is not position to start searching from, but position to end on.

> pos -
>   Position of the last character in the string to be considered in the search.
>   Any value greater than, or equal to, the string length (including string::npos) means that the entire string is searched.
>   Note: The first character is denoted by a value of 0 (not 1).

In your case, you can simply drop second argument and you'll recieve correct position in `pos2`
or
if you want to get text between qoutes you can use this code

```
std::string ss="<tag2 name = \"Name1\">";
std::size_t pos1=ss.find_first_of("\"");
std::size_t pos2=ss.substr(pos1+1).find_first_of("\"");
std::cout<<ss.substr(pos1+1,pos2)<<std::endl;
```

Comment: cplusplus.com is not a good reference, try cppreference.com instead.